# Unir Query en una sola con JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy intentando unir varias sentencias SQL en una sola, el problema es que tiene un JOIN y y no sé como renombrar las tablas

```
 SELECT users.nombre,users.apellido,users.id,
 COUNT(ligauruguaya_v.primero) AS Primero  FROM users LEFT JOIN
 ligauruguaya_v ON users.id = ligauruguaya_v.primero WHERE
 users.categoria < 3  GROUP BY users.id

 SELECT users.nombre,users.apellido,users.id,
 COUNT(ligauruguaya_v.segundo) AS Segundo FROM users LEFT JOIN
 ligauruguaya_v ON users.id = ligauruguaya_v.segundo WHERE
 users.categoria < 3  GROUP BY users.id

 SELECT users.nombre,users.apellido,users.id,
 COUNT(ligauruguaya_v.tercero) AS Tercero FROM users LEFT JOIN
 ligauruguaya_v ON users.id = ligauruguaya_v.terceroWHERE
 users.categoria < 3  GROUP BY users.id
```

esa serían las sentencias uno a uno pero necesito que sea en una sola...

```
SELECT users.nombre,users.apellido,users.id, COUNT(ligauruguaya_v.primero) AS Primero, COUNT(ligauruguaya_v.segundo) AS Segundo, COUNT(ligauruguaya_v.tercero) AS Tercero, 
        FROM users 
        LEFT JOIN ligauruguaya_v ON users.id = ligauruguaya_v.primero,
        LEFT JOIN ligauruguaya_v ON users.id = ligauruguaya_v.segundo,
        LEFT JOIN ligauruguaya_v ON users.id = ligauruguaya_v.tercero
        WHERE users.categoria < 3 
        GROUP BY users.id
```

y el error que me da es:

> ## 1066 - Tabla/alias: 'ligauruguaya_v' es no unica

intenté con `ligauruguaya_v AS pepe,` etc. pero no lo logré

Comment: podes mostrar como trataste de hacer el AS? porque esa es la forma en la que tenes que hacerlo

Comment: SELECT users.nombre,users.apellido,users.id, COUNT(pepe.primero) AS Primero, COUNT(pep.segundo) AS Segundo, COUNT(pe.tercero) AS Tercero
            FROM users 
            LEFT JOIN ligauruguaya_v AS pepe ON users.id = pepe.primero
            LEFT JOIN ligauruguaya_v AS pep ON users.id = pep.segundo
            LEFT JOIN ligauruguaya_v as pe ON users.id = pe.tercero
            WHERE users.categoria < 3 
            GROUP BY users.id

Comment: algun coma mal puesta porque ahora me funciono

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT users.nombre,users.apellido,users.id, COUNT(pepe.primero) AS Primero, COUNT(pep.segundo) AS Segundo, COUNT(pe.tercero) AS Tercero
            FROM users 
            LEFT JOIN ligauruguaya_v AS pepe ON users.id = pepe.primero
            LEFT JOIN ligauruguaya_v AS pep ON users.id = pep.segundo
            LEFT JOIN ligauruguaya_v as pe ON users.id = pe.tercero
            WHERE users.categoria < 3 
            GROUP BY users.id
```

De seguro tenia alguna coma mal